# Can mercury escape undectectably from a CFL bulb? or does it have to shatter for the mercury to be liberated?

Tags: pressure, gas, inert-gases

I read that the mercury vapour inside a fluorescent lamp is pressurized at 0.2% of atmospheric pressure.

Can mercury escape undectably through a small crack in the glass yet still light up? Or will the pressure difference cause it to explode and/or stop working?